# Material UI App Bar Component's menu does not show up after toggle

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, frontend, material-ui

I am playing round with App Bar and Drawer Components in Material-UI. Whenever I click on Hamburger menu in App Bar the Drawer toggles. But my Hamburger icon is like completely covered. So if i want my Drawer menu to toggle out I have to refresh the page. My Components are as follows:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <AppBarComponent />


     </div>
   </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
 }
}
```

AppBarComponent.js

```
  class AppBarComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar title="App Bar Title"
          iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
          onLeftIconButtonClick={this.handleToggle}
        />
        <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
          </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default AppBarComponent;
```

[image]

Whenever i click on the hamburger menu the drawer toggles as:

[image]

As we can see that the hamburger menu is complety covered. How can i make the App Bar component responsive? Do I have to write css class manually or is there any way to tweak it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one solution that might be is, you can toggle the Drawer on the righthand side.
openSecondary property is available in Drawer component, you can make it boolean value true to toggle from left-side.

Comment: openSecondary property just toggles the Drawer component on the right. My question is how can I toggle it without covering the Hamburger menu on the default side.

Answer (score 0):

You can possible set the z-index of the drawer to something lower than the AppBar's z-index. Change the AppBar position to absolute and the drawer to relative.  Might have to play around with padding but couldn't hurt.